# Go syscall FILE_NOT_FOUND but process has a valid procedure address

Tags: go, system-calls, ffi

I am trying to create a golang package for PCAN CAN handling based on a .dll file.
The package and all the code below can be found here: https://github.com/morgadow/gocan

Now I have a problem while using the syscall package for a .dll function call.
On one call i get the error FILE_NOT_FOUND (2), but the process i am calling has a valid process number.
Other calls are working just fine.

No matter what i try, i can not get the syscall call to work.
I made 100% sure, the function calls are aligning to the .dll documentation.
If you have any idea what i can try next, i will be happy to try it out and provide code examples.

Thank you in advance,
Simon

My code:
For example when trying this, it works just fine:

```
var channel TPCANHandle = PCAN_USBBUS1
var baudRate TPCANBaudrate = PCAN_BAUD_500K
var hwType uint32 = PCAN_TYPE_ISA  // not relevant
var ioPort TPCANHandle = 0x02A0  // not relevant
var interrupt uint16 = 11  // not relevant

ret, _, errCall := syscall.SyscallN(pHandleInitialize, uintptr(channel), uintptr(baudRate), uintptr(hwType), uintptr(ioPort), uintptr(interrupt))
```

When using this function, the return value is error FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).
I tried with a initialized and a not initialized channel with same result.

```
var channel TPCANHandle = PCAN_USBBUS1
ret, _, errCall := syscall.SyscallN(pHandleUninitialize, uintptr(channel))
```

Functions:

```
func Initialize(channel TPCANHandle, baudRate TPCANBaudrate, hwType TPCANType, ioPort uint32, interrupt uint16) (TPCANStatus, error) {
    ret, _, errCall := syscall.SyscallN(pHandleInitialize, uintptr(channel), uintptr(baudRate), uintptr(hwType), uintptr(ioPort), uintptr(interrupt))
    return TPCANStatus(ret), sysCallErr(errCall)
}
```

```
func Uninitialize(channel TPCANHandle) (TPCANStatus, error) {
    ret, _, errCall := syscall.SyscallN(pHandleUninitialize, uintptr(channel))
    return TPCANStatus(ret), sysCallErr(errCall)
}
```

Process Numbers for both handles:
`pHandleInitialize: 140710484398192 = 0x7ff9b6705070`
`pHandleUninitialize: 140710484399952 = 0x7ff9b6705750`

Getting Process adresses:

```
pHandleInitialize, err = syscall.GetProcAddress(pcanAPIHandle, "CAN_Initialize")
pHandleUninitialize, err = syscall.GetProcAddress(pcanAPIHandle, "CAN_Uninitialize")
```

Both calls return no error and the process id above.

**Edit 08.09.2023:**

Based on the suggestions of kostix, i tried to rewrite all the calling of the DLL using the syscall.LoadDll and DLL.FindProc and then the Proc.Call methods.
The result is the same, i get procedure addresses without any errors, but on calling the actual procedure CAN_Unitialize, a ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error is raised. Other calls are working just find.

All code of this tests can be found in github under the branch *changing_call_architecture*.

Here a screenshot of the procedure address:
[image]

Comment: Please augment the code snippets in your question with the following information: 1) how `channel` is defined; 2) C API for `CAN_Initialize` and `CAN_Uninitialize`. If needed, also include the definitions of the types they refer to. Basically, it's only interesting what type they expect their 1st argument to be, respectively. I conjure the former expects a pointer to something, and the latter expects that plain something, not a pointer to it. But I need more information.

Comment: Well, if the API is [this](https://documentation.help/PCAN-Basic/) then my hypothesis regarding pointer vs non-pointer is wrong.

Comment: Hello @kostix, thanks for the answers and sorry for the late response due to holiday. I updated the description above. Thanks for the link i was not aware of this and worked with the datasheet from PEAK Systems which says basically the same.

Comment: I think I have an idea: you're using `syscall.SyscallN` to call a procedure from a _regular DLL,_ not a procedure which is a part of Win32 API. While I'm not 100% sure it's the cause, it still may be because of possibly differing [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Let's try the following: 1) Use `syscall.LoadDLL` to load the PCAN DLL; 2) On the resulting value, call `MustFindProc` to find those `CAN_*` symbols; 3) On the resulting values, use `Call`, as documented, and see if that works.

Comment: A minor nitpick: the "Proc" in `GetProcAddress` stands for ["procedure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_programming)), not "process"; they are vastly different concepts, so don't mix them up. Also, what `GetProcAddress` returns is not merely "a number", it's an address (in the memory of your running process) of the procedure's code (the first machine code instruction of the procedure).

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try your suggestions. And also thanks for the other comment, it is Always good to learn something new.

Comment: @kostix: The link about calling conventions was really interesting!

Comment: I have tested your suggestion but unfortunately without achieving a better result, see changes above.
Which of the versions is the "better" one now? I'm not sure which one to keep, as both achieved an equivalent result for me. ideally, the code would be designed to run on linux and windows, and a LoadDLL function seems very windows-specific to me?

Comment: LoadDLL is absolutely Windows-specific, but your question implicitly talked only about Windows right from the start (because DLLs are Windows-specific). Particluar addresses returned by using no matter which mechanism are not interesting at all: we see the functions theirselves work (if the addresses were incorrect you'd get "hard" system-level errors such as "access violation").

Comment: Basically I'm out of suggestions now. In this case, it worth partitioning the problem space to understand whether the problem is on Go side, or with that particular PCAN library or the way you're calling it or some issue with how that PCAN library works on your particular system and so on and so on. Usually, a way to go would be to first move Go out of the picture by  writing and building a minimal C program which would do the same calls of that DLL and see whether that works. I don't think we have much to do with this particular SO question.

Comment: One more note regarding calling external libs from Go: programs running on Linux-based systems (that's an incorrect term as Linux, being an OS kernel, has nothing to do with loadable libraries and do not even know they exist) _usually_ are not supposed to load shared libraries at runtime. While doable (POSIX defines [`dlopen(3)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/dlopen.html), and GNU libc [supports it](https://manpages.debian.org/3/dlopen)), Go does not provide any direct wiring for this feature in its `syscall` package–in contrast to Windows. …

Comment: …This dichotomy is pretty much defined by "common usage patterns": it was useful to be able to load DLLs on Windows _for Go core itself,_ and so its `syscall` package has such support; it wasn't usefult for Go itself to load arbitrary .so files on Linux-based systems, so there's no direct support for it. OK, so, for Linux, you're supposed to use [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)–which requires a working C toolchain when building your program; `cgo` will make sure to link your program against the required libraries. And it's done differently to your current approach to support Windows.

Comment: Anyway, as you can see we've already pushed the limits of the SO comments feature beyond its limits: if you want some lecturing on how to do such things _after_ you have read the material linked above, feel free to pick a more suitable venue from [this list](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/#the-go-community). I would recommend the mailing list but it's up to you, and other venues might also work for you.

Comment: Oh, and while we're at it, `cgo` is not only about Unix-like systems; it's perfectly possible to use it for Windows programs, and it will provide much the same result: the required DLLs will be linked against your program while it's being loaded for execution, but this creates the build-time dependency on a working C toolchain, and while, again, doable on Windows, its commonly considered to be an extra burden compared to explicit loaing of the required DLLs at runtime.

Comment: One more point: if you'll ask a question using a venue other than SO–like the mailing list, Go forum etc–please post there a link to your question, if possible.